# Translating HEX ACLs into permissions

Tags: windows, ubuntu, active-directory, samba

I'm trying to write a script to scrape Samba share ACLs from my Ubuntu server machine. I've been using `smbcacls` to read permissions per file/folder. When a user only has `RX` or `WX` permissions, it's fine, but as soon as a user has anything labelled a "special permission", it shows up in hex.

Example:

`user@machine: ~$ smbcacls //server/share folder_1/ --authentication=.credentials`

Prints:

```
REVISION:1
CONTROL:SR|PD|DP
OWNER:SERVER\Admin
GROUP:SERVER\everyone
ACL:SERVER\Admin:ALLOWED/0x0/0x001e01ff
```

The `0x0` is related to inheritance, but what does this `0x001e01ff` mean? It looks like binary flags `00000000111100000000111111111`, but I can't find any documentation on what these mean.

Any tips/links to documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the SDDL meanings are documented e.g. here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/f4296d69-1c0f-491f-9587-a960b292d070

meaning of `0x001F01FF` for example is "file full access"

0x001F01FF = 0x001E01FF + 0x00010000 (which is delete-> see link). this means the delete permission is missing in your calcs result. bit wise permissions are built by adding the atomic hex permissions

Comment: I've accepted this answer, because I hadn't seen that before and it seems to explain a lot. However, 0x001E01FF isn't listed, but it's one bit away from 0x001F01FF, so maybe there's something I'm missing

Comment: @alex-nvx 0x001F01FF = 0x001E01FF + 0x00010000 (which is delete-> see link). this means the delete permission is missing in your calcs result. bit wise permissions are built by adding the atomic hex permissions

Answer (score 0):

[Falco's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/988386/94065) is typically going to be more useful, but for completeness, the individual file permissions flags are documented under [File Access Rights Constants](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-access-rights-constants) in the Windows Dev Center, and the standard and generic flags are documented under [ACCESS_MASK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-mask).

Breaking down 0x001E01FF, we have:

- 0x00100000 = SYNCHRONIZE (used by the kernel? not too sure exactly what this does!)
- 0x00080000 = WRITE_OWNER (take ownership of the file)
- 0x00040000 = WRITE_DAC (change permissions on the file)
- 0x00020000 = READ_CONTROL (see the existing permissions on the file)

And also

- 0x00000100 = FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES (change the file attributes)
- 0x00000080 = FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES (see the file attributes)
- 0x00000040 = FILE_DELETE_CHILD (delete all children - applies only to folders)
- 0x00000020 = FILE_EXECUTE (run the file / traverse the folder)
- 0x00000010 = FILE_WRITE_EA (write extended attributes)
- 0x00000008 = FILE_READ_EA (read extended attributes)
- 0x00000004 = FILE_APPEND_DATA (append data to a file, or create a subfolder)
- 0x00000002 = FILE_WRITE_DATA (write data to a file, or create a file in a folder)
- 0x00000001 = FILE_READ_DATA (read data from a file, or list the folder contents)

But we notably don't have

- 0x00010000 = DELETE (delete the file)